# Is it possible to track user presence from different topic?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I use Phoenix framework for my Elixir application with WebSocket connection. I have two different topics, one for users and other for admins. Admin should see which users are present. I decided to use `Presence` module from Phoenix. Unfortunately, you can send current `Presence` state only to socket which start tracking.

Example code:

```
def join("users", params, socket) do
  socket |> assign(:user_id, params[:user_id])

  send(self, :after_join)
  {:ok, socket}
end

def join("admins", _params, socket) do
  {:ok, socket}
end

def handle_info(:after_join, socket) do
  push(socket, "presence_state", Presence.list(socket))

  {:ok, _} = Presence.track(socket, socket.assigns[:user_id], %{
    online_at: inspect(System.system_time(:seconds))
  })

  {:noreply, socket}
end
```

I want to listen for an event in admins' front-end application for presence changes. Is it possible to do it with `Phoenix.Presence`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `YourApp.Endpoint.broadcast/3`:

```
def handle_info(:after_join, socket) do

  {:ok, _} = Presence.track(socket, socket.assigns[:user_id], %{
    online_at: inspect(System.system_time(:seconds))
  })
  YourApp.Endpoint.broadcast "admins", "presence_state", Presence.list(socket)

  {:noreply, socket}
end
```

and listen `presence_state` from your adminChannel:

```
adminChannel.on("presence_state", state => {
  presences = Presence.syncState(state)
  // doSomethingWithPresences
}
```

You should separate `YourApp.AdminChannel` and `YourApp.UserChannel`

When your client receive `presence_diff` event.You can push it to user channel and use `Endpoint.broadcast/3` again:

```
userChannel.on("presence_diff", diff => {
  userChannel.push("presence_diff", diff)
}
```

in `YourApp.UserChannel`:

```
def handle_in("presence_diff", diff, socket) do
  YourApp.Endpoint.broadcast "admins", "presence_diff", diff
  {:noreply, socket}
end
```

And now you can listen your `presence_diff` event:

```
adminChannel.on("presence_diff", diff => {
  presences = Presence.syncDiff(diff)
  render(presences)
}
```

Comment: That was helpful. Do you have an idea how to handle "presence_diff" event? I get presence when user connects to channel, but when admin will log later that user, he will receive empty presence state.

Comment: I tried your idea and it doesn't work as it should. When user logs out presence stare that admin watches doesn't update. It happens, when it's one user online. Simply there no other user to notify admin channel about presence difference. I will dig it, I saw that if you have channel pod you cab track it's presence, see: https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Presence.html#c:track/4. So now I need to get channels pid.

Answer (score 1):

If you're setting up presence tracking within one of the channel's callback handlers (like `handle_info/2`), you can add tracking on an arbitrary topic like:

`Presence.track(self(), "admins", socket.assigns[:user_id], %{some_metadata: "whatever"})`

Then, elsewhere in another process you can subscribe to the `admins` topic like:

`YourApp.Endpoint.subscribe("admins")`, at which point that process will start receiving `presence_diff` messages.